# Tableau on Spark Sql performance benchmarks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api, presto, exasolution

Are there benchmarks for SparkSql being used as the primary reporting  warehouse for Tableau? Size of the reporting warehouse is in a few TBs.

How does SparkSql's performance compare against Redshift, Exasaol and Presto for use with Tableau? What are the challenges faced?

There are benchmarks for SparkSql's query performance against many of [them](http://s3.amazonaws.com/8kmprod/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/17093304/8KMiles_WhitePaper_BigData-solution-Benchmark2.pdf) here. I am looking for case studies, benchmarks as well as any issues faced specifically with Tableau.